# What is the font used in the Image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I am planning to create a typographic logo ,when i searched online i found this image quite interesting.What is the font used in the below image or is there any font similar to it

[image]

Comment: Probably not a font, but a custom drawing.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Custom Design. You can manipulate the font to make such things if you want to. There are lots of tools available to manipulate fonts. I would suggest, you build your own custom font (if possible) or own design. It will keep the logo unique until someone comes up with your logo and ask for what font it is ? :)